# How to encapsulate a collection?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class A
{
    private Set<String> users = new HashSet<String>();

    public Set<String> getUsers()
    {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers( Set<String> users )
    {
        this.users.clear();
        if( users != null )
        {
            this.users.addAll( users );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        A a = new A();
        Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>();
        temp.add( "a1" );
        temp.add( "a2" );
        a.setUsers( temp );
        Set<String> previousUsers = a.getUsers();
        System.out.println( previousUsers.size() ); //output 2

        temp.add( "a3" );
        a.setUsers( temp );
        System.out.println( previousUsers.size() );//output 3, how to make it still 2?
    }
}
```

Question: if i want `previuosUsers` still keep the old values after new setUsers been called, how should i modify this program?

Comment: Is this your homework? If yes, try it out on your own first. HINT: - `Don't clear your Set. Just append to the end`.

Comment: The interface is setUsers(), not addUsers(), append may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this constructor instead [`public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29), than just directly assigning the return to `previousUsers`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public Set<String> getUsers()
{
    return (Set<String>)users.clone();
}
```

> if i want previuosUsers still keep the old values after new setUsers been called.

It means that the collection modified within `setUsers` must not be same as what is pointed by `previousUsers`. So, within `getUsers` return a copy of the collection instead of a reference to same collection. and that's what [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) does.

Comment: I don't think Set has a method "clone"

Comment: clone() is a method of java.lang.Object so every object in Java inherits it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class A
{
    private Set<String> users = new HashSet<String>(), prevUsers = new HashSet<String>();    
    public Set<String> getUsers()
    {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers( Set<String> users )
    {
        this.prevUsers = new HashSet<String>(users); // saves a copy of users in prevUsers
        this.users.clear();
        if( users != null )
        {
            this.users.addAll( users );
        }
    }
    public Set<String> getPrevUsers() { 
        return this.prevUsers; 

    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Set<String> previousUsers = a.getPreviousUsers();
        System.out.println( previousUsers.size() ); //output 2

        temp.add( "a3" );
        a.setUsers( temp );
        System.out.println( a.getPreviousUsers.size() );//output 3, how to make it still 2?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are expecting

```
 public Set<String> getUsers()
{
    Set<String> users1 =  new HashSet<String>();
    users1.addAll(users);
    return users1;
}

public void setUsers( Set<String> users )
{
    this.users = users;

}
```